# InvalidCastException, wrong context?

Tags: c#, dll

I have an exe that does data dumps.  The exe will dynamically pick up DLL's based on configuration and pass a class object into it.   The DLL has a copy of this class compiled with it and can see the data, under debug, without a problem as an object.  However, when I try to cast that to the class, it tells me it can't because of the context.   I'm sure I've overlooked something as I do that at times.

**Error:**

> [A]MyClass cannot be cast to [B]MyClass. Type A originates from
>   'MyExe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the
>   context 'Default' at location 'C:\MyPath\MyExe.exe'. Type B originates
>   from 'MyDLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in
>   the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\MyPath\MyDLL.dll'.

**EXE Code:**

```
Object[] param = new Object[] { MyClass };
MethodInfo m = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
reader = (SqlDataReader)m.Invoke(obj, param);
```

**DLL Code:**

```
public SqlDataReader MyMethod(Object param)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = new SqlDataReader();
    Type t = param.GetType();  //Returns MyClass

    if (param is MyClass)      //Returns false
        reportItem = (MyClass)param; //Never executes

    MyClass reportItem = (MyClass)param; //InvalidCastException

    //other code here, pulling data
    return reader;
}
```

Comment: My guess is you have to dynamically create the class object that you pass in as a parameter. OR inside MyMethod, create a new MyClass using the properties on the passed in object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The DLL has a copy of this class compiled with it

Don't do that, basically. You should have the type in *one* assembly, and only one assembly. As far as the CLR is concerned, these are entirely different types.

You probably want to have a common library which both the plugins and your application can refer to. Or you could make your plugins refer to the application executable and keep the type within there.

Comment: I have common objects, between the two, but they are specifically for SQL or Logging.  I'll create another and give it a try for this one.   Thanks.